# How to convert string to int in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

```
monthwise_sub = list(map(int, read_from_csv(infile_csv, month=True)[1]))
```

When i run this ,i get

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "(1, 0, 'Friday')"
```

Comment: Can you share  a [MCVE]?

Comment: You're passing `"Friday"` to `int`. What do you want the output to be?

Comment: @user3080953 Not `"Friday"`, `(1, 0, 'Friday')`.